# Moving minor updates between local and live sites - just database?

Tags: database, migration, localhost

So after I have created my site on my localhost, and moved it over (files + database + config to new url etc...) I continue to work off the localhost version.

The sites are identical. I then add some posts and pages and edit the css file. To update the live site, would I just update the database and the css file that was edited? Those were the only things that were edited, but I'm not sure if I have to reconfig the database at all or run some type of refresh or update in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only changed some CSS, then updating the CSS file on the live server should be sufficient (unless you need to clear a cache or something).

If you changed/created posts on your localhost - then those posts will *not* be on your live site. You could overwrite the live site's database with your localhost database - however then you will lose any data that was created on the live site (for example, comments).

In general, if the posts/pages you're creating on localhost are supposed to also be on the live site, you're better off creating them there in the first place.

Comment: Another option would be to export on localhost and import on your live site, so you can transfer the posts and pages without destroying any content on the live site. Not sure how well that deals with duplicates, though.